# How to dynamically render an input value of type=file in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I got an input field of type='file', what I am trying to achieve in my nuxt project is showing the filename that is uploaded, to the user. I know that by default input type=file is already showing the value but i made the input's opacity 0 for styling purposes.

I have tried to write a function that finds the filename selected with the input. Then i assigned the file name to a reactive variable with ref() and returned that variable in that function. Then i put that reactive variable inside double curly braces to render it dynamically in the page and called the function everytime input value changes.

The function:

```
<script setup>

 const inputField = ref(null);
 var fileName = ref(null);

 function changeFileName(file) {
   if (file.files[0] != null) {
     return (fileName = file.files[0].name);
   } else return (fileName = "");
 }

</script>
```

Where I called it in the code:

```
<template>
 <div>

  <b>{{ fileName }}</b>

  <input
   type="file"
   ref="inputField"
   @change="changeFileName(inputField)"
  />

 </div>
</template>
```

So I expected to change the variable "fileName"'s value everytime users select a file from their computer and render the value dynamically to show which file is selected but it seems like curly braces ( {{}} ) is not catching the changed value because after selecting a file, fileName's value is changing but the old value continues to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bind the reactive property with input value using `value` and `change` event, and assign value to the ref property using `.value` field :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const fileName = ref("")
 function changeFileName(e) {
   console.log(e)
   if (e.target.files[0] != null) {
      fileName.value = e.target.files[0].name;
   } else  fileName.value = "";
 }
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ fileName }}</h1>
  <input  type="file" :value="fileName" @change="changeFileName"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Using .value to get the value of the reactive variable solved my problem, thanks!